# Can't initialize GraphQL: wrong ANTLR Tool runtime version

Tags: java, servlets, graphql, antlr

My application fails at the first query trying to initialize GraphQL with this error:

> ANTLR Tool version 4.7.2 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.5.1

I don't explicitely use this library in my project, I tried to add a newer version to the pom nothing changed.
Original issue: https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-java-servlet/issues/241

Full stack trace:

```
ANTLR Tool version 4.7.2 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.5.1ANTLR Runtime version 4.7.2 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.5.1Apr 06, 2020 4:54:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at graphql.parser.Parser.parseDocument(Parser.java:57)
    at graphql.parser.Parser.parseDocument(Parser.java:39)
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParserBuilder.parseDocuments(SchemaParserBuilder.kt:181)
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParserBuilder.parseDefinitions(SchemaParserBuilder.kt:169)
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParserBuilder.scan(SchemaParserBuilder.kt:162)
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParserBuilder.build(SchemaParserBuilder.kt:207)
    at it.cims30.core.api.graphql.GraphQLEndpoint.createSchema(GraphQLEndpoint.java:23)
    at it.cims30.core.api.graphql.GraphQLEndpoint.getConfiguration(GraphQLEndpoint.java:17)
    at graphql.kickstart.servlet.AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.init(AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.java:85)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1079)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2300)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATN; Could not deserialize ATN with UUID 59627784-3be5-417a-b9eb-8131a7286089 (expected aadb8d7e-aeef-4415-ad2b-8204d6cf042e or a legacy UUID).
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNDeserializer.deserialize(ATNDeserializer.java:153)
    at graphql.parser.antlr.GraphqlLexer.<clinit>(GraphqlLexer.java:276)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATN; Could not deserialize ATN with UUID 59627784-3be5-417a-b9eb-8131a7286089 (expected aadb8d7e-aeef-4415-ad2b-8204d6cf042e or a legacy UUID).
    ... 32 more

Apr 06, 2020 4:54:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [it.cims30.core.api.graphql.GraphQLEndpoint]
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATN; Could not deserialize ATN with UUID 59627784-3be5-417a-b9eb-8131a7286089 (expected aadb8d7e-aeef-4415-ad2b-8204d6cf042e or a legacy UUID).
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNDeserializer.deserialize(ATNDeserializer.java:153)
    at graphql.parser.antlr.GraphqlLexer.<clinit>(GraphqlLexer.java:276)
    at graphql.parser.Parser.parseDocument(Parser.java:57)
    at graphql.parser.Parser.parseDocument(Parser.java:39)
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParserBuilder.parseDocuments(SchemaParserBuilder.kt:181)
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParserBuilder.parseDefinitions(SchemaParserBuilder.kt:169)
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParserBuilder.scan(SchemaParserBuilder.kt:162)
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParserBuilder.build(SchemaParserBuilder.kt:207)
    at it.cims30.core.api.graphql.GraphQLEndpoint.createSchema(GraphQLEndpoint.java:23)
    at it.cims30.core.api.graphql.GraphQLEndpoint.getConfiguration(GraphQLEndpoint.java:17)
    at graphql.kickstart.servlet.AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.init(AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.java:85)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1079)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2300)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Comment: The issue seems to be resolved looking at the Github issue: https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-java-servlet/issues/241#issuecomment-609954931 @AlessandroTagliani, perhaps provide an answer to you own question and accept that?

Comment: @BartKiers you're right, sorry. Gonna do that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current solution is (from the closed issue):

> Revert graphql-java-tools to 5.7.1 and graphql-java to 13.0

The current version isn't compatible with graphql-java 14.0.
I also needed to add to my pom this:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
  <version>3.10</version>
</dependency>
```

The graphql-java-tools I reverted to used a different version of commons-lang3 that gave a NullPointerException if the JDK version was too new (I'm using 13).